# Why the background image of Linearlayout not showing in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some layout question for Android , the following code is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.wen.test.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item1_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_signal">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item2_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems like the following picture:

[image]

**Question:**
Why the background of `dashboard_item1_layout` and `dashboard_item2_layout` did not show via following code?

```
android:background="@drawable/no_signal"
```

But I can set the background image to the `dashboard_layout`.
Did I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to use Relative layout. First user Linear Layout (set its orientation vertical) in that use other linear layout and set its orientation Horizontal.So the first 2 small images will come under the second linear layout whose orientation is horizontal and third image will come under first linear layout.Ya and change layout height of linear layout to wrap content instead of 0dp

Comment: Because the layout_height of linear layout is

Comment: What is the root layout? Please attach full code.

Comment: @HaiHack Edit it.

Comment: @Arjun I have try. It is not working.

Comment: @Wun It works as you expected when I run it

Comment: @HaiHack Can you post the code in the answer let me reference ?

Comment: Seems Ok to me . What is `no_signal` if its a drawable then check if its drawing any shape or not .

Comment: @ADM It is OK to show in the android studio preview layout . But it fail on the Android phone.

Comment: Thats what i  am asking if its a drawable xml do you have it in all Api levels ? Like drawable and drawable-v21 and drawablev-24 ?It can be be the issue if you testing on lower then 21 and do not have the file inside `drawable`.

Comment: But I can set the background image to the first `Linearlayout(dashboard_layout)`. I think the drawable is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do nothing except adding background for `dashboard_item1_layout` and `dashboard_item2_layout` as you expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item1_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/like_outline">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item2_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/like_star_outline"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set background in your code is ok but the problem seems like in no_signal.xml file. Can you show code this file?

Comment: It is a png image not a xml file.

Comment: oh. you check this image is too large, resize to smaller

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on your phone. I just added background as expected in your code. Also, replace background image with the native one. If it is run then issue with your asset only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_red_fab"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item1_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_item2_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel">

        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```